# How do I read a file, append it's contents?

Tags: python, file-io

I am new to programming in general, specifically using Python. I am trying to write a function which takes a file as a parameter, appends the contents (while type casting to float) and returns the average. The file is called "stuff.txt" and is small, consisting of:

```
3
2
1
4.0
5.0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def my_average(file):
    numbers = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            numbers.append(float(f.readline()))
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)


my_average('stuff.txt')
```

It keeps trying to cast the string 'stuff.txt' to a float and throwing errors. help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the file actually have the string `stuff.txt` inside it? As written, the only bug in your code is that you're throwing away the even-numbered lines (the ones read into `line` implicitly in the `for` loop), only storing the odd-numbered ones (from the `readline` call).

You can fix that by changing the loop to:

```
def my_average(file):
    numbers = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            numbers.append(float(line))  # Convert the line you've got, not a new one from readline
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

If some of the lines might be invalid floats, e.g. because the file begins with `stuff.txt`, you can silently ignore those lines by catching the exception from parsing them and ignoring it:

```
def my_average(file):
    numbers = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                numbers.append(float(line))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
```

Comment: 'stuff.txt' is just the file name. Which could be a problem itself. I'm getting a "file not found" error as well. I definitely have that file name in my directory, could it be the way I'm passing it into the function?

Comment: @agiuchin Try using the file’s full path.

Comment: @agiuchin: Is the file in your *working* directory, or the *script's* directory. For example, if you're in `/home/agiuchin` for example, and you run `python3 path/to/my/script.py`, it will only work if `stuff.txt` is in `/home/agiuchin`, *not* if it's in `/home/agiuchin/path/to/my/`. Try using a fully qualified path as AMC says, so there is no doubt about where it is looking.

Comment: @agiuchin: I'd suggest including the full traceback of the error in your question; I suspect you're seeing one error and misinterpreting it as something else.

Comment: Okay, you guys were right. After using the file path, i got it to run finally (no errors). However, it still won't return the average. It just finishes the process.

Comment: @agiuchin: You don't use the return value. Change `my_average('/path/to/stuff.txt')` to `print(my_average('/path/to/stuff.txt'))` if you want to print it.